# Find all sequences $f(0), f(1), f(2), . . .$ such that $∆f(x) = 2019f(x) + 2020$, where $x ∈ \mathbb N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, finite-differences

I have this question which I'd appreciate some help on how to tackle it.

So far I've converted it into the recurrence relation 
$f(x+1) = 2020f(x) + 2020$

With the solution $f(x) = \alpha(2020)^x+\beta$, but I am unsure what the values of alpha and beta are.

Comment: What is $\Delta f(x)$? Is it $f(x+1) - f(x)$?

Comment: If you do not have more information such as the values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ then you cannot go any further

Comment: @IshanDeo yep that's right

Comment: @Henry I'm trying to express the values in terms of f(0)

Comment: $f(1)=\alpha\cdot 2020^0 + \beta$ and $f(2)= \alpha \cdot 2020^1+\beta$ and you know $f(1),f(2)$ in terms of $f(0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can use generating functions to solve given recurence.
Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1482664/698145) and [this](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eaf1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf).
In your case it will be
$$ a_{n+1} = 2020 a_n + 2020  \\
... \\
A(x) = 2020A(x) + \frac{2020}{1-x}$$
And that should be continued. At the finish think about that, how you can write your solution in terms of $f_0$.